# How can I retrieve the data from a given node by looking at the data saved in the child?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrieve data from the node **"questions posts"** ONLY IF the child **topic** has the value of **"finance"**. Any ideas on how that can be accomplished? I have been trying to do this but with no luck.

```
 DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("questions posts");
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            financeList.clear();

            if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("topic") && dataSnapshot.child("topic").getValue().toString().equals("finance")){
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Finance finance = snapshot.getValue(Finance.class);
                    financeList.add(finance);
                }

                financeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                progress_circular.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Ashish's answer works, please note that when you are using the following reference:

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("questions posts");
```

And attach a listener on it, you are reading all the children that exist beneath that `questions posts` node. I see that right after that, you filter the results on the client, which is actually not the right approach since reading an entire node might be considered a waste of bandwidth and resources. Basically, you are telling Firebase, hey Firebase give me all the data and I do my filtering on the client. The best option that you have is to create a query, and filter the results directly on the server:

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("questions posts");
Query query = reference.orderBy("topic").equalTo("finance");
query.addValueEventListener(/* ... */);
```

So basically you are getting now only the results you are interested in. Suppose you have in the `questions posts` node 1000 objects and you are looking for only three of them. Imagine what would be the size of the result set when getting all 1000 objects? I can imagine that it will be huge. If you use the query, the result will be very small size, because only three elements will be returned and **not** 1000.

Comment: Hello Alex, how about retrieving the data by looking at the "publisher" child? I tried this  Query query=reference.orderByChild("publisher").equalTo(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());  but it could not fetch any data.

Comment: @willy Without seeing the code, unfortunately, I cannot be much of a help. So for that, please post a new question using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Answer (score 1):

According to your code it's finding the child of questions post. But he finds only document id's in it. So just iterate through the document id's and then get the child `topic` and make condition on it.

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("questions posts");
reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        financeList.clear();
        for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            if(snapshot.child("topic").getValue(String.class).equals("Finance")){
                Finance finance = snapshot.getValue(Finance.class);
                financeList.add(finance);
            }
        }
        financeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        progress_circular.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```